# having trouble compling this code for a starwars name generator

Tags: java, computer-science

I need to use  first three letters of actual first name + first two letters of actual last name, and first two letters of mother's maiden name + first three letters of birth city. I also need to have the first letter be capitalized. Using toUpperCase() and toLowerCase(). Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");
    /* This should be string as your gettting name*/
    String firstname = input.nextLine(); 
    firstname = firstname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstname.substring(1);
     /* Don't need new variable use same and that also should be string. */
    System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");

    String lastname = input.nextLine();
    lastname = lastname.substring(0,2). toUpperCase() + lastname.substring(1);

    System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
    String mothersname = input.nextLine();
    mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,2);

    System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
    String cityname = input.nextLine();
    cityname = cityname.substring(0,3);

    String StarWarsName = firstname+lastname+mothersname+cityname;
    System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + StarWarsName );
}

  }

//* Updated code 
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstname = input.nextLine(); 
        firstname = firstname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstname.substring(1).toLowerCase();

    System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");
    String lastname = input.nextLine();
    lastname = lastname.substring(0,1). toUpperCase() + lastname.substring(1).toLowerCase(); 

    System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
    String mothersname = input.nextLine();
    mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,2);

    System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
    String cityname = input.nextLine();
    cityname = cityname.substring(0,3);

    String StarWarsName = firstname+lastname+" "+mothersname+cityname;
    System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + StarWarsName );
}

  }
```

Comment: What trouble are you having?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - firstname cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - input cannot be resolved

Comment: Where do you declare `firstname`? What type is it? Where do you declare `input`? What type is it?

Comment: Also, what type does the `substring()` method return?  What is the type of the variable(s) to which you attempt to assign that value?

Comment: I declared the firstname with  `int firstname = input.nextLine(); ` . I didnt declare input, not sure how to do that. I am using  `Substring() ` to take the first 3 of the first name and first two of last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected the code and explained the changes in comments. Go through comments also. Don't just copy this code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     Scanner input = new Scanner();
    System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");
    /* This should be string as your gettting name*/
    String firstname = input.nextLine();
     /* Don't need new variable use same and that also should be string. */
    firstname = firstname.substring(0,1);
    System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");

    String lastname = input.nextLine();
    lastname = lastname.substring(0,2);

    System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
    String mothersname = input.nextLine();
    mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,1);

    System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
    String cityname = input.nextLine();
    cityname = cityname.substring(0,2);

    String StarWarsName = ( "firstname"  + "lastname " + "mothersname " + "cityname"); 
    System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + StarWarsName );
}

  }
```

Comment: So you just deleted the `int firstname = input.nextLine();` and last name etc... then declared it as a string? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: The output is: `May the force be with you, JOEoeSMmithApSan` when it should be `May the force be with you, Joesm Apsan.`

Comment: all these are fundamentals. SO is there to give some hints or ideas no body will not entire write code for you. You need to follow those those instructions. @patm

Comment: I just can't seem to figure out how to use only the first 3 letters of the first name...

Answer (score 0):

> firstname cannot be resolved to a variable

1. You didn't declare `firstname`. Not only `firstname` you didn't declare `lastname`, `mothersname`, `cityname`. So you should declare all. Those should be `String`.
2. You didn't create `Scanner` object. Create `Scanner` class object.

   ```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   ```
3. Next change. You declared `cityname` as two times and as `int`type. But [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) returns `String` not `int`.

   ```
   String cityname = input.nextLine();//returns String, not int
   cityname = city.substring(0,3);//returns the first 3 characters as String, not int
   ```

[String#substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) returns `String` not `int`. So check the entire code.

4. Change

   ```
   String StarWarsName = ( "firstname"  + "lastname " + "mothersname " + "cityname");
   ```

to

```
   String StarWarsName = firstname+lastname+" "+mothersname+cityname;
```

All these are variables not values. So don't put in double quotes.

**Edit:** Capitalize the first letter of `firstname`

```
   firstname = firstname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstname.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I updated the code, but I am still getting errors. "Multiple markers at this line
 - firstname cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - firstname cannot be resolved
 - firstname cannot be resolved"

Comment: Before using any variable you should declare it first. So declare `firstname` before using it. same as the `lastname`. Add this line `String  firstname= input.nextLine();`

Comment: So I would do `int firstname= input.nextLine();`

Comment: It should be of `String` type not `int`. Since `nextLine()` returns `String` not `int`.

Comment: Don't change your code. It will effect to other answers. @patm

Comment: Okay won't anymore still new to this. The code posted above is my most recent and it won't compile still.

Comment: `String firstname = input.nextLine();           ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Assignment2
Assignment2.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    String lastname = input.nextLine();
                      ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Assignment2
Assignment2.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    String mothersname = input.nextLine();
                         ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Assignment2
Assignment2.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    String cityname = input.nextLine();
   ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Assignment2`

Comment: Since you missed my `2` point. That should be the first statement.

Comment: I added the `Scanner input = new Scanner();` but It still says `Exception in thread "main"`

Comment: Okay this is the error I am getting: `Assignment2.java:7: error: reference to Scanner is ambiguous
      Scanner input = new Scanner(null);
                      ^
  both constructor Scanner(String) in Scanner and constructor Scanner(ReadableByteChannel) in Scanner match
1 error`

Comment: 2. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)`.

Comment: The output is: `May the force be with you, JOEoeSMmithApSan` when it should be `May the force be with you, Joesm Apsan.`

Comment: see my complete answer and don't capitealize `lastname` , `cityname` @patm

Comment: I made the changes you told me but I am still not getting the correct output and the last name has the first two characters capital still.

Comment: first read my entire answer with edit and follow same to others.

Comment: I read your entire answer and fixed the issue with the capitalization, but I am still getting extra characters. `May the force be with you, JoeSmith ApSan`

Comment: I updated the code in the question (didn't delete previous code) take a look at it